# Car inconsistently won't start

Tags: honda, battery, starting, crv, corrosion

My 2013 Honda CR-V will occasionally not start. It cranks fine but will not actually start. If I turn the car on but don't try to start it, electronics and everything else seem to be fine. I noticed some corrosion on the positive terminal when I was trying to jump it. It will usually start fine when I jump it. I had the battery tested and they said it was a perfectly good battery.
I'm hoping once I clean off the corrosion, my problem will go away. One time when I had to jump it, it wouldn't even start with the jump, but then I repositioned the positive lead on my car and it started. I'm no mechanic, but I am pretty sure the issue is my battery's connection, but the more I read online, the more worried I get about it being my alternator. Could this be an alternator problem? I had also read online that it could be a fuel supply issue, but since it starts with a jump, it couldn't be a fuel supply issue, right?

Comment: "Could this be an alternator problem?" not if it eventually starts without a jump. What might be happening is the corrosion is causing the battery voltage too low for electronics to work (<9v) while cranking. Clean the terminals with baking soda and water, remove the terminals and clean the cable end and the battery contact with a small wire brush and baking soda solution., reassemble and tighten.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm gonna give it a few days before declaring victory haha! I will report back soon.

Comment: Be sure to remove, clean, and tighten all grounds.

Comment: I Was just about to declare victory after cleaning the corrosion away and having many successful ignitions today, but just now my car wouldn't start EVEN with a jump this time. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @nitrusinc is that different than cleaning the connection to the battery? I removed those connections, cleaned with baking soda and reattached and tightened.

Comment: @Phillip Byram Cleaning the battery terminals is good, but the grounds should be attended to as well. There should be a wire leading from your negative battery terminal to a "blank" spot on the chassis. Blank as in it's not feeding anything, just a screw into the side of the engine bay. You should find other grounds similar to this, leading from the engine to the chassis, likely of a thinner wire. You want to remove them clean them and the fasteners and then reinstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!
It turned out that when I got my battery tested and they said it was "good" they were reading it after the battery had been charged from driving it. I had it tested again this morning and it was in fact a bad battery.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question. This will greatly help the next person with the exact same problem!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the connections at both ends of both battery cables are clean and tight. Corrosion at one end of a cable suggests there may be corrosion at the other end as well.

If the car usually starts, and always starts when jumped, then the issue is unlikely to be an alternator or fuel flow problem.

Comment: Sorry I prematurely marked this as the answer. Will update in a few days :)